# Using AVPlayer to make audio tinny (adjust playback EQ).

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer

I would like to be able to have music playback that can allow me to make the audio tinny. Like an  Equalizer, i would like to alter the Channel EQ of the audio using a slider to choose whether the audio is full and rich, or light and tinny during playback of the audio file. Is this implementation possible?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have a basic music player that I have used following a tutorial found here:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk_background-audio--mobile-6833